# Graphing an exponential function and its inverse on the same Cartesian plane

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to graph an exponential function and its inverse on the same Cartesian plane using TikZ (or pgfplots).  I have code using TikZ. Apparently, there is an error in the `\addplot` command.

I would like to plot y = 2^{x} and y = \log_{2}(x).  (The code is for e^{x} and \ln(x). I was not sure how to enter "\log_{2}(x)" in TikZ.)  The exponential function should be labeled "y = 2^{x}" towards the top, where its graph ends, and the logarithmic function should be labeled "y = \log_{2}(x)" towards the bottom, where its graph ends.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt}]
\draw[<->] (-7,0) -- (7,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[<->] (0,-7) -- (0,7) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[<->, dashed] (-6.5,-6.5) -- (6.5,6.5) node[right]{$y=x$};
\addplot [color=green]  {exp(x)};
\addplot [color=blue]  {ln(x)};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but $\log_2 x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}$.

Comment: `\addplot` only works inside an `axis` environment. So you don't need those axis drawing commands either. Pgfplots does it for you

Comment: I am currently teaching students how to change bases for logarithms in a Calculus course.  I know that there is a command for graphing the logarithm with base 2 ... without using the change-of-base formula.

Comment: `log2(x)`, see chapter 90 of the manual for `pgf`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a quick example;

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,
          xmax=10,ymax=10,
          axis lines=middle,
          restrict y to domain=-7:12,
          enlargelimits]
\addplot[green]  {pow(2,x)} node[above]{$y=2^x$};
\addplot[blue,domain=1/2^6:10,samples=100]  {log2(x)} node[above left] {$y=\log_2(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the command \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}?  It seems that "xmax=10,ymax=12," instructs pgfplots to draw the x-axis to the right 10 units. What code told it to draw the x-axis to the left only 6 units or 7 units? You specify the domain for the logarithm function with "domain=1/2^6:10". Why didn't you have to specify the domain with the exponential function?

Comment: @user143462 exponential function domain is `$(-\infty,\infty)$` while `log` function is not defined for negative values.

Comment: @user143462: for your questions about `pgfplots` it could be good to take a look at its documentation. It contains some `tutorial` chapters. You can also find nice `pgfplots` examples in http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/

Comment: @user143462 I think you need to distinguish pgfplots from TikZ first even though one is built on another. Axis options are best understood via the manual of pgfplots, in short I want to constrain the visible part of the plot even though pgfplots might have produced the curve up to x=10 which would go to 1024 so log would be almost invisible. Then I also constrain the plot to be produced at max 12. The rest of the details is as Ignasi commented.

Answer (score 7):

For any TikZ solution at least there is one solution in PSTricks. But the converse is not necessarily true.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\pslegend[rt]
{
    \color{blue}\rule{5mm}{1mm} & \color{blue}$f(x)=2^x$ \\
    \color{red}\rule{5mm}{1mm} & \color{red}$f(x)=\log_2(x)$
}
\begin{psgraph}[algebraic]{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(7,7){12cm}{!}
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{-2.5}{2.5}{2^x}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{2 -2.5 exp}{2 2.5 exp}{log(x)/log(2)}
    \psplot[linestyle=dashed]{-2}{6}{x}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: forward is not true either

Answer (score 7):

This is another approach with `TikZ`

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, samples=100]
\draw[->] (-3.8,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-4) -- (0,5) node[left] {$y$};
\node at (-2.8,-3)[above] {\footnotesize\color{gray} $y=x$};
\draw[smooth, domain=-3.8:2.3, color=green, thick] 
    plot (\x,{2^(\x)}) node [right] {\footnotesize $f(x)=2^x$};
\fill [green] ($(0,1)$) circle (1.5pt) node at (0,1.2)[left] {\color{green}$(0,1)$};
\draw[smooth, domain = 0.06:5, color=blue, thick] plot (\x,{log2(\x)});
\fill [blue] ($(1,0)$) circle (1.5pt) node at (1.4,0)[below] {\color{blue}$(1,0)$};
\node at (4.6,2.4)[above] {\footnotesize\color{blue}$f^{-1}(x)=\log_2 x$};
\draw[smooth, dashed, domain=-2.5:4.5, color=gray] plot (\x,\x);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) based on TikZ:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\tzaxes*(-7,-7)(15,15){$x$}{$y$}
\def\Fx{2^\x}
\tzfn[blue,thick]\Fx[-5:ln(12)/ln(2)]{$f(x)=2^x$}[ar]
\tzfn'[red,thick]\Fx[-5:ln(12)/ln(2)]{$f(x)=\ln_2 x$}[ar] % inverse
\tzfn[dashed]{\x}[-5:12]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```