# Plot a function of logarithm with PGFplots

Tags: pgfplots

How do I plot a function of a logarithm with PGFplots? 
Say that I want to plot y=log_3(x).
I have a simple Latex code for function y=log_2(x), but I don't know how I can write function of a logarithm with base 3 and others values of base.

Here is Latex code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,
          xmax=10,ymax=4,
          axis lines=middle,
          enlargelimits]
\addplot[latex-latex,smooth,black,mark=none,%samples=140,
line width=1.5pt,domain=-3.5:9.5,
samples=63,
color=red]  {log2(x)} node[above left] {$y=\log_2(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is a graphic of the function

[image]

If someone knows how to solve this problem and show it through the example, I'll be grateful.

Comment: This is more a math question, `log_3(x)=log_2(x)/log_2(3)`. So just do `\addplot[latex-latex,smooth,black,mark=none,%samples=140,
line width=1.5pt,domain=-3.5:9.5,
samples=63,
color=blue]  {log2(x)/log2(3)} node[above] {$y=\log_3(x)$};`.

Comment: @current_user, i'm not sure, that all member of this site understand your comment :-). better is stay at official language of site (čeprav je mnogokrat lažje po domače).

Comment: Related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200316/graphing-an-exponential-function-and-its-inverse-on-the-same-cartesian-plane/405286#405286

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,
          xmax=10,ymax=4,
          axis lines=middle,
          enlargelimits]
\addplot[latex-latex,smooth,black,mark=none,%samples=140,
line width=1.5pt,domain=-3.5:9.5,
samples=63,
color=red]  {ln(x)/ln(3)} node[above left] {$y=\log_3(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comment and by current_user, you only have to apply basic logarithm relations. One can actually define a function for this with

```
\tikzset{declare function={Log(\n,\x)=log2(\x)/log2(\n);}}
```

The MWE thus becomes

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{declare function={Log(\n,\x)=log2(\x)/log2(\n);}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,
          xmax=10,ymax=4,
          axis lines=middle,
          enlargelimits,xmax=12.5]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2,3,10}
{
\addplot+[latex-latex,smooth,mark=none,
line width=1.5pt,domain=-3.5:9.5,
samples=63]  {Log(#1,x)} node[right] {$\log_{#1}(x)$};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]